# Displaying LoginViewController for several "auth only" views

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an app where I'd like to allow users to use few screens without authentication. However if user tries to go to checkout or account areas - I want to display login controller.
Because my app has quite large number of views and it has "deep linking" it is not enough to check if I should display LoginViewController only "entry point" views. E.g. using deep linking user can open app with "Wallet" view loaded (which is inside Account view). So checking if user authenticated in only in `AccountViewController` isn't enough and I need to check that at each child view controller too.

Because of that I decided that I need universal way to check if user led in and do this check on each view which requires authentication.

I implemented extension on `UIViewController`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func displayAuthIfNecessary() {
        let token = AuthManager.sharedInstance.token
        if (token == nil) {
            var loginStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LoginStoryboard", bundle: nil)
            let viewcontroller : UIViewController = loginStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginNavigationController") as! UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(viewcontroller, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And I call this method in each `viewWillAppear` where I need to check authentication.

The problem is - "auth only" view (e.g. `AccountViewController`) is displayed first and **only then** my `LoginViewController` is presented.
Is there a way to display it before?
**Example:** When `AccountViewController` presented modally - modal animation should display `LoginViewController` if user isn't logged in and `AccountViewController` if user is logged in. Right now it presents `AccountViewController` and then switches to `LoginViewController`.

And the second question - is there a nicer way to display `LoginViewController` in different places? Probably using extensions for that isn't a great idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following method in my AppDelegate:

```
func presentLoginViewController() {
    weak var vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginNavigationController") as? UIViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
}
```

My LoginNavigationController is separate from other navigation controllers, so that it is not tied to other navigation flows in the storyboard.